# BigQuery : how to make a MERGE operation fail on some conditions?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-update, sql-merge

I want to update a target table (`target`) according to rows in a source table (`source`). For that, I use the [`MERGE` statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement). However, I would like the whole `MERGE` operation fails on some conditions, but cannot figure how to do.

#### Example

The `target` table contains :

```
id
==
1
2
```

The `source` table contains :

```
id | operation
==============
3  | ADD
4  | DELETE
```

Expected `target` table after `MERGE` (I don't want **any** update here because `4` corresponds to `DELETE` operation, and since there is no `4` line in `target` table, this is considered as an error and `MERGE` should fail atomically) :

```
id
==
1
2
```

As of now, I use the following request :

```
MERGE `target` target
USING `source` source
ON target.id = source.id
WHEN not matched AND source.operation = "ADD" THEN
  INSERT (id)
  VALUES (source.id)
```

But obviously, I got :

```
id
==
1
2
3
```

---

Is it possible to add in my query a clause like :

```
WHEN not matched AND source.operation = "DELETE" THEN ERROR("...")
```

This does not work (`ERROR` is unexpected) :

> Syntax error: Expected keyword DELETE or keyword INSERT or keyword UPDATE but got identifier "ERROR"

If this is not possible with `MERGE` query, is there a way to rewrite it to a similar query to update atomically my `target` table as I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate an error yourself.  Something like:

```
WHEN not matched AND source.operation = 'DELETE' THEN 
    INSERT (id)
       VALUES ( CAST(source.operation as int64) )
```

I haven't intentionally tried to generate errors in BigQuery, but I don't think there is a function that automatically does so.

As proposed by @norbjd:

```
WHEN not matched AND source.operation = 'DELETE' THEN 
    INSERT (id)
       VALUES ( ERROR('ERROR:  DELETE operation encountered') )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The destination type in `CAST` cannot be `int` (not a valid BigQuery type) but `numeric`, `int64`, or something else valid; however, the solution still applies.

Comment: In BigQuery, the `ERROR` function exists to generate an error (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/debugging_functions#error), but is not usable as-is, as only `DELETE` or `INSERT` is expected after `WHEN ... THEN`. But based on your solution, I could write : `INSERT (id) VALUES (ERROR('Error message'))` to have a clearer message, even if it seems like a hack.